# Not all the buttons are displayed

Tags: wysiwyg

I installed CKEditor plugin ver. 1.16. In configuration page for editor appearance I selected "Full":

[image]

But when I open "Add content" page I see the different picture:

[image]

When I changed the appearance from "Full" to "Advanced", the appearance doesn't change. But when I switched to "Basic" appearance, it worked.

What's the issue here? Why not all the buttons are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

On 'Add content' page, please check which '**Text format**' you have selected in drop-down below the CKEditor.

Make sure that you have selected the **Full HTML** or **Filtered HTML** according to your field settings.

Comment: I did it from the beginning - "Full HTML" was selected.